# Adding bookmark to merged PDF's using pyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, bookmarks, pypdf

I need to add bookmark to the new merged created pdf. I use a script that merge all pdfs from the curent directory using pyPDF2. I will be good to have bookmark structured with the name of the each pdf's. Each PDF it may have 1-2-3 pages.

Code that's working for merging all pdf's from directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from glob import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
def merge(path, output_filename):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    for pdffile in glob(path + os.sep + '*.pdf'):
        if pdffile == output_filename:
            continue
        print("Se adauga '%s'" % pdffile)
        document = PdfFileReader(open(pdffile, 'rb'))
        for i in range(document.getNumPages()):
            output.addPage(document.getPage(i))

    print("S-a creat pdf '%s'" % output_filename)
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as f:
                output.write(f)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    # Add more options if you like
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                        dest="output_filename",
                        default="Test.pdf",
                        help="write merged PDF to FILE",
                        metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path",
                        dest="path",
                        default=".",
                        help="path of source PDF files")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    merge(args.path, args.output_filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PyPDF2 `PdfFileMerger` method, which takes a bookmark string as the second argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from glob import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

def merge(path, output_filename):
    merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    for pdffile in glob(path + os.sep + '*.pdf'):
        if pdffile == output_filename:
            continue
        print(f"Appending: '{pdffile}'")
        bookmark = os.path.basename(pdffile[:-4])
        merger.append(pdffile, bookmark)
    merger.write(output_filename)
    merger.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    # Add more options if you like
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                        dest="output_filename",
                        default="Test.pdf",
                        help="write merged PDF to FILE",
                        metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--path",
                        dest="path",
                        default=".",
                        help="path of source PDF files")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    merge(args.path, args.output_filename)
```